# React ChatJS-2: How to get x-axis label on clicking the label?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm using react-chartJS-2 , I want to get the respective label element on clicking the label.

[image]

In the above image on clicking the date suppose `Apr 24th` , I want to get the respective element of `Apr 24th`.

I have already tried using , `onClick` inside `options` and also i tried `getElementAtEvent` ,`getElementsAtEvent` and `getDatasetAtEvent`. But nothing is working.

Since , it is a `canvas` element so normal `onClick event` will also not work.

Is there any possible way to solve it? Kindly help.

Comment: will you please share the most recent code?